# How to prove that $e^{-\gamma}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac1n\right)e^{-1/n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, gamma-function, products

Suppose we defined the Gamma function
$$\frac1{\Gamma(z)}=ze^{\gamma z}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac zn\right)e^{-z/n}$$
where $\gamma$ is just a constant. I want to prove that $\Gamma(1)=1$, so I need to prove that
$$e^{-\gamma}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac1n\right)e^{-1/n}\tag{*}$$

From definition, by taking logarithm and then differentiating, we arrive to
$$\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}=-\frac1z-\gamma-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{z+n}-\frac1n\right)\tag{1}$$
which implies that
$$\frac{\Gamma'(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+1)}-\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}-\frac1z=0\tag{2}$$
taking integral we arrive to the following identity
$$\Gamma(z+1)=Cz\Gamma(z)\tag{3}$$
where $C$ is constant and since $\lim_{z\to0}z\Gamma(z)=1$, so 
$$C=\Gamma(1)\tag{4}$$
I tried to from identities $(1-4)$ arrive to $(*)$, but failed, can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Shouldn't taking the logarithm and using
$$\gamma = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{k} - \log(\frac{k + 1}{k}))$$
suffice?

Comment: you get that $\Gamma(z+1) = z \Gamma(z)$ and $\Gamma(1) = 1$ but proving this is equal to $\int_0^\infty x^{z-1} e^{-x} dx$ requires more steps, I think you also need to show there is only one log-convex analytic function on $Re(z) > 1$ fulfilling  $f(z+1) = zf(z)$, $f(1) = 1$

Comment: @user1952009 Note that I want to prove that $\Gamma(1)=1$, we don't have it!

Comment: @user302007 : what is $\gamma$... as the other told you, the usual definition is the constant such that $f(z+1) = z f(z)$ with $f(z)$ your product

Comment: @user1952009 I don't know. This is a problem in Ablowitz-Fokas complex variables where the authors didn't give more information about $\gamma$!

Comment: will you repeat this 50x ? did you read what everybody wrote ? and did you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant ?? I know you didn't so do it.

Answer (score 6):

In order to prove that $C=1$, you need to prove that:
$$ \gamma = \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) \tag{A}$$
but that is exactly the usual definition of the Euler-Mascheroni costant, since:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) = H_N-\log(N+1).\tag{B}$$

Comment: I don't know, but this is a problem in Ablowitz-Fokas complex variables where authors don't give more information about $\gamma$, page 171, problem 3.6.6.d?

Comment: @user302007: if you defined the $\Gamma$ function through its Weierstrass product you need some definition of $\gamma$, otherwise what is the meaning of $\gamma$ in you first line? You cannot ask to prove that $\Gamma(1)=1$ for *any* constant you put there, but the above lines show that $\Gamma(1)=1$ is equivalent to $$ \gamma = \lim_{N\to +\infty}\left(H_N-\log N\right).$$